# Link to reputation league appears only after clicking "Summary" link in profile page

Tags: bug, profile-page, reputation-leagues

I have noticed this in all the SE where I am registered:

When I view my own profile page for the first time, the reputation frame looks like this:

[image: no link to reputation league]

Note, there is no link besides "Reputation".

Then, when I click on Summary in the left profile page nav bar, the same frame look like this:

[image: link to reputation league is there]

Notice that the link to the reputation league has now appeared, while it wasn't present on the first time, and it's exactly the same page and view.

Comment: No repro, chrome on android.

Comment: This link appears only in "Summary" view, which *should* be the default, but somehow it's not. (That's likely the bug)

Comment: @Luuklag you probably clicked "Summary" sometime in the past after the new redesign, so it kept your selection and it's your default view. Try it on a new site.

Comment: @ShadowWizardHatesOmicron it is also present in the profile itself, but at the top, next to the amount of uestionsnyou've asked etc.